# Problems with relative pronouns

Tags: relative-pronouns

I have a question related to punctuations. Please tell me whether the following sentences are correct or not.

1. Innodata is a company that provides BPO and KPO services.
2. Innodata is a company providing BPO and KPO services.
3. Innodata is a company, providing BPO and KPO services.

Is it always correct to replace "that" with a comma after changing the verb into "ing" form?

Comment: This question is probably more suited to [ell.se].

Answer (score 4):

> Innodata is a company that provides BPO and KPO services.
>
> Innodata is a company providing BPO and KPO services.

Both are correct and mean the same thing. The last option, however is not correct.

> Innodata is a company, providing BPO and KPO services.

The clasue "providing PBO and KBO services" is a restricting clause: it limits the set of companies you're talking about. A comma is not used before a restricting clause.

Compare:

> There is a boy playing in the garden.

This sentence does not refer to any boys not playing in the garden.

> There's our son, playing in the garden.

This sentence is about "our son". It just so happens that he's playing in the garden. Hence this is a non-restricting clause and a comma is OK.